# Which dependency required to call dagger interface

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to use dagger to in my Android project. after importing the below posted dependencies, I am able to use the annotations
but I can not use the Dagger Interface which is the `@Component`. for example, if my interface is called "MyComponent", and when I 
want to use it as follows:

```
DaggerMyComponent.build()
```

I found that DaggerMyComponent is not defined and I can't use it. Please have a look at my `Gradle` files and let me know if there is any thin missing

**gradle:project**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' //added apt for source code generation

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.App**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pc_amr.dagger_1"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11' // if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

**interface component**

```
@Module
public class VehicleModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
Motor provideMotor(){
    return new Motor();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
Vehicle provideVehicle(){
    return new Vehicle(new Motor());
}
```

}

**main**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VehicleComponent component = DaggerVehicleComponent//Not recognised
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your module and component declaration ?

Comment: @pdegand59 please find the component declarion posted.would you please let me know whther or not the dependencies required for Dagger are correct or not?

Comment: you forgot the VehicleComponent interface, the one annotated with `@Component`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I had to modify the build.gradle(App) and and the following dependencies:

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```